# Statement after sending message keeps active in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am sending a messages back and forth from background.js to the content script when a certain condition has been met `String(historyItems.length) == "0"`. It works fine, but I noted that once the message has been sent once (not before that), the function `displayMe();`at the other end is active, even when the when the condition has not been met.

background.js:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  chrome.history.search({
    text: request.text,
    maxResults: 10
  }, function(historyItems) {
    if(String(historyItems.length) == "0"){
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
          });
        });
    }
  });
```

contentscript.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello"){
      displayMe();
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    }
});
```

It is all triggered with this function in contentscript.js:

```
function buildUrlList(){
  document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    var hoveredEl = event.target;
    if (hoveredEl.tagName !== 'A') {
      return;
    } 
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({text: "Trigger Search"});
  });
}
```

I just want the function in the content script activate when the background.js send the message (once). How can I make this work (javascript only)?

Comment: mouseover event is sent for every nested (descendant) DOM element so "Trigger Search" is sent multiple times. Start using devtools debugger properly: set breakpoints inside callbacks of the content script and the background script, run the code, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! The dev tools put me back on the right track.

Comment: Also, your `chrome.tabs.query()` assumes that you only have a single tab open in the current window. If you want to assume that `tabs[0]` is the active tab in the current window, you should use `{active:true,currentWindow:true}`.

Comment: Another time, please provide code in one code block per file. Please do not break out functions from the same file into multiple code blocks. For Chrome extensions, please also include a *manifest.json*, as that file has a significant impact on what happens in the extension. Ideally, we should be able to copy-&-paste your code blocks, one per file, into the named files and be able to duplicate the problem.